# Winforms multithreading scenario question

Tags: winforms, multithreading

this morning I saw some strange code from one of my coworkers. In an winforms application the whole Mainform was given into a thread as reference.
He did this to invoke methods from the Form. Nothing to interact with the UI, just plain calculation methods.
I am already sure this is not a best-practice but I wonder something. If I call methods from the Mainform from inside a thread are these methods still processed as multithreading? Or do they run inside the Mainform?
Will the UI thread be affected when I call methods from the Mainfrom from a thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions from the form called from a different thread will run on the thread that is calling them and have no effect on the GUI thread.  As a side effect, this means that if you call a function that interacts with the GUI you will get an exception.

If you want them to be called on the GUI thread, the easiest thing to do is call `Control.Invoke(...)` which causes the delegate you pass in to be executed on the GUI thread, allowing GUI interaction.